# Customize kendo grid filter

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid which is set up with default filters. However, I would like to change the look and feel of those, and provide my own.

What I want to accomplish is to get rid of the dropdowns, and put some checkboxes with my different option and filter as soon as I select a checkbox.

Is this possible?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can put whatever you want.

**Grid columns**

```
{
    field: "City",
    width: 130,
    filterable: {
       ui: cityFilter
    }
},
{
    field: "Title",
    filterable: {
         ui: titleFilter
    }
},
```

**Filter UI defining**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function cityFilter(element) {
    element.kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: "@Url.Action("FilterMenuCustomization_Cities")"
            }
        },
        optionLabel: "--Select Value--"
    });
}

function titleFilter(element) {
    element.kendoAutoComplete({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: "@Url.Action("FilterMenuCustomization_Titles")"
            }
        }
    });
}
```

You can modify and put checkbox dropdownlist autocomplete datepicker and ...

[reference](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/filter-menu-customization.html)

Answer (score -1):

This link from the official telerik documentation did help me: [Checkbox filter menu filtering](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/how-to/checkbox-filter-menu). The main idea is to use the filterMenuInit event to insert custom templates for every column needed.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Ok. I got your point. But why downvote? The tooltip I see at the downvote arrow is "The answer is not useful". I guess you haven't searched desperately for this link and for everyone who does, this answer is definitely helpful. Even if the link changes, a quick search for the title should reveal the needed information and if not, the information is not valid anymore anyway. Beside that, this is code from telerik - don't know what kind of copyright problems might come up here. I hope no one will _not_ post an answer because he is afraid of a downvote. I prefer a link instead of nothing...